# Messed up service request in ROS2 service node with direct DDS request

Tags: ros, ros2, rosservice, dds, fastdds

I have the problem that I need to communicate with a ROS2 application via DDS from another application that is not a ROS2 application itself, but only uses DDS (Opensplice).

I have managed to send DDS topic instances of a custom, non-trivial type to the ROS application by customizing the idl files for my Opensplice application according to the ROS naming conventions. This works fine and the ROS2 program receives the messages completely.

Now I want to use this for ROS2 services as well and have written an Opensplice program that is able to send a service request message containing a Vector3 from the standard ROS2 message types. Everything is built correctly, but when my ROS program receives the request, I have the problem that the x component of the request in the ROS program contains the number from the z component of the Opensplice message and the y and z components are zero.

I can see the Opensplice messages in the Opensplice tester and all 3 components are set correctly there. So what is causing the problem? Is this some sort of deserialization problem on the ROS-side? But why does it work with topics? My ROS programm is using CycloneDDS.

I really hope someone here can help me because I really can't find the problem. I can go into more detail about how I set up the idls and named the topics etc, but I think this is not the cause of my problem.

**Update:**
When I change the RMW_IMPLEMENTATION variable to "rmw_fastrtps_cpp", so FastDDS, it is working. So, this seems to be problem with the CycloneDDS-Opensplice communication. Does anyone know more about this?

Kind regards